# Proving that $f(\{x\})=\{f(x)\}$ for all $x\in X$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, proof-explanation

> Prove that $f(\{x\})=\{f(x)\}$ for all $x\in X$

Suppose $\gamma\in f(\{x\})$. Then there exists $\alpha\in\{x\}$ such that $f(\alpha)=\gamma$; namely, $\alpha=x_i$ for some $x_i\in X$. Thus, $\gamma=f(\alpha)=f(x_i)$; that is, $\gamma\in\{f(x)\}$.

Suppose $\gamma\in\{f(x)\}$. Then $\gamma=f(x_i)$ for some $x_i\in X$. That is, $\gamma\in f(\{x\})$.

Hence, $f(\{x\})=\{f(x)\}$.

Does this look correct? Any suggestions on how to improve it perhaps or have I gone wrong anywhere?

Comment: If you choose $\alpha\in \left\{x\right\}$, then $\alpha=x$. for each $x\in X$, $\left\{x\right\}$ is a set with only one element.

Comment: So for the first part I can omit the "for some $x_i\in X$, but what about the second part?

Comment: For the second part, if $\gamma \in \{ f(x)\}$, then $\gamma = f(x)$, so $\gamma \in f(\{ x\})$ since $x \in \{ x\}$. I am repeating because I don't know why the subscript $x_i$ is present.

Comment: Your second part should be something like: "Suppose that $\gamma\in\{f(x)\}$. Then $\gamma=f(y)$ for some $y\in\{x\}$. That is $\gamma=f(x)$ or equivalently $\gamma\in f(\{x\})$." It is not forbidden to use $x_i$ instead of $y$, but you better don't. It is causing confusion and is only justified if something has been said about that index $i$ falling from the sky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's just unwrap the definitions. If $f\colon X \to Y$ and we choose any $x \in X$, observe that:
\begin{align*}
f(\{x\})
&= \{f(\alpha) \in Y \mid \alpha \in \{x\}\} \\
&= \{f(\alpha) \in Y \mid \alpha = x\} \\
&= \{f(x)\} \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more direct way:
$$f(\{x\}) = \{f(y):y\in\{x\}\} = \{f(y):y=x\} = \{f(x)\}$$
since $y\in\{x\}\iff y=x$.

Answer (score 1):

In this context think of $x$ as a **fixed** element of $X$.

It can all be done shorter (see the answers) but on purpose I stick to your line of reasoning.

---

If $\gamma\in f(\{x\})$ then $\gamma=f(y)$ for some $y\in\{x\}$.

For $y$ there is only one choice: $y=x$.

So eventually we find $\gamma=f(x)$ or equivalently $\gamma\in\{f(x)\}$.

Proved is now that: $$f(\{x\})\subseteq \{f(x)\}\tag1$$

---

If $\gamma\in\{f(x)\}$ then automatically $\gamma=f(x)$ or equivalently $\gamma\in\{f(y)\mid y\in\{x\}\}=f(\{x\})$.

Proved is now that: $$\{f(x)\}\subseteq f(\{x\})\tag2$$

---

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we find:$$f(\{x\})=\{f(x)\}\tag3$$

This has been proved for an arbitrary fixed $x\in X$ allowing the conclusion that $(3)$ is true for **every** $x\in X$

Answer (score 0):

You need to prove that given a specific x,  f({x})={f(x)}.
What you proved is that given x,  if γ∈f({x} then there is some xi∈X such that γ∈{f(xi)}. That is also true but does not prove the needed equality, since you want to have xi = x .

Suppose γ∈f({x}). Then f(x)=γ. Thus, γ∈{f(x)}.

Suppose γ∈{f(x)}. Then γ=f(x)  Thus, γ∈f({x}).

So we see that f({x})={f(x)}